# R Populating a dataframe in a for loop

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this problem that makes no sense to me.

```
TickerList <- c("NAB.AX", "WES.AX", "TLS.AX", "CSL.AX", "WPL.AX", "SUN.AX")
for (Ticker in TickerList)
{
tickerdata.w <- get.hist.quote(Ticker, start = "2000-01-01",compression = "w", quote = "AdjClose")

#This is to get Continuous Compounding Return

ticker.log.data <- log(lag(tickerdata.w)) - log(tickerdata.w)

#This should give the name of the ticker to the log data
#eg, the first one will end up with a NAB.AX

assign(Ticker, ticker.log.data)

#Now I want to get the first data into a dataframe.
#So I want MyData to hold the NAB.AX log data.
#I know the loop works but there is something wrong with assigning the ticker data to the dataframe.

  if (Ticker == TickerList[1]) {
    MyData = (Ticker)

#And now the rest are to be merged into the dataframe

   } else { 
   MyData = merge(MyData, Ticker)
   }
}
```

However, it just does not work. The only thing that goes into the dataframe is the name such as NAB.AX not the data.

Any guidance would be most welcome.

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. What is get.hist.quote? What package does it live in?

Comment: I inadvertently (perhaps niavely) thought that when I assigned the Ticker to the data.frame that the Ticker would become the ticker.log.data. After throwing in some prints, I discovered that the ticker.log.data still existed after the assign and I was able to use that data.frame to populate MyData in the if loop. I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Sorry, the get.hist.quote is in library(tseries).

Comment: I realise that there are much easier ways of getting historical data but I am after the CCR instead of the normal data that comes from other packages that rely on end of day changes. I want to use adjusted figures as I would rather use DataStream information if it is available.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tseries)

rm(list=ls())

TickerList <- c("NAB.AX", "WES.AX", "TLS.AX", "CSL.AX", "WPL.AX", "SUN.AX")

for (Ticker in TickerList)

{
tickerdata.w <- get.hist.quote(Ticker, start = "2000-01-01",compression = "w", quote = "AdjClose")

ticker.log.data <- log(lag(tickerdata.w)) - log(tickerdata.w)

assign(Ticker, ticker.log.data)

  if (Ticker == TickerList[1]) {

    Stock.DF <- (ticker.log.data)

  } else { 

    Stock.DF <- merge(Stock.DF, ticker.log.data)
  }
}
head(Stock.DF)

names(Stock.DF) <- c("NAB", "WES", "TLS", "CSL", "WPL", "SUN")

TSData = as.timeSeries(Stock.DF)

Data = na.omit(TSData)
```

Comment: Stylistic tip: use <- or = uniformly (<- is preferred)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that what you want is a data frame with the ticker symbols as the column names and the log data as the rows, but that wasn't quite clear from the question.

Building up a data frame with a for loop is not a common R idiom, despite its prevalence in other languages. A better approach is to use an `apply` function (which does use a for loop under the hood).

First, define a function to return the log data given a ticker symbol.

```
getData <- function(symbol) {
   tickerdata.w <- get.hist.quote(symbol, start = "2000-01-01", 
      compression = "w", quote = "AdjClose")

   ticker.log.data <- log(lag(tickerdata.w)) - log(tickerdata.w)
   ticker.log.data <- ticker.log.data[1:778,] # ensure equal length 
   return(ticker.log.data)
}
```

Note that most of the symbols you provided give a result of length 778, but one gives length 780. If you want a data frame, all must have the same length, so the commented line in `getData` truncates.

Next, apply that function to each symbol. This generates a list. Rename the elements of the list with their symbols.

```
TickerList <- c("NAB.AX", "WES.AX", "TLS.AX", "CSL.AX", "WPL.AX", "SUN.AX")
MyData <- lapply(TickerList, FUN = getData)
names(MyData) <- TickerList
```

Finally, convert from a list to a data frame.

```
MyData <- data.frame(MyData)
```

Note that your call to `get.hist.quote` with those symbols results in a warning message  about the length of the downloaded file. I didn't look into those messages, but you may want to.

Comment: I did notice that WES had an issue as the data had not been posted to Yahoo Finance since a capital return. Thanks for pointing it out. Thanks for your reply as well.